# Identification of an old postcard

Tags: world-war-2, world-war-1, photo-identification

A question quite very similar to [this one](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/14868/8670). I have an old postcard, probably around WW2 era, probably sent from Germany. Unfortunately this postcard is empty when it comes to handwriting or otherwise personal elements:

[image]

[image]

This postcard may be the only existing element to identify a missing person in my family tree and thus the most important part for me is to **identify the age of this post card or a year when it was published**. Which could allow to estimate the year this postcard was actually sent and by this -- to verify or reject the suggestion that this particular person (assumed to be the one, who sent this card) was living and that given age.

I managed to figure out that this particular postcard includes a reproduction of [Carl von Bergen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_von_Bergen)'s painting -- one of many around "feeding the ducks" theme (like [this one](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimages.fineartamerica.com%2Fimages%2Fartworkimages%2Fmediumlarge%2F1%2Ffeeding-the-ducks-tanya-gordeeva.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Ffineartamerica.com%2Ffeatured%2Ffeeding-the-ducks-carl-von-bergen.html&docid=lvczOR2HnOAlqM&tbnid=BwX4oVE-T6zgNM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwilz76p8aziAhVsyaYKHQ-MB6IQMwhEKAUwBQ..i&w=662&h=900&bih=625&biw=1366&q=Carl%20von.%20Bergen%20painting&ved=0ahUKEwilz76p8aziAhVsyaYKHQ-MB6IQMwhEKAUwBQ&iact=mrc&uact=8) or [this one](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fimg.nagimg.com%2Fdata%2F1680%2F1680056.jpg&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.niceartgallery.com%2FCarl-Von-Bergen%2FZwei-Madchen-Beim%250D-Entenfuttern-oil-painting.html&docid=TX9vmp0Ylq8oUM&tbnid=MCfFfHN6vJE7sM%3A&vet=10ahUKEwilz76p8aziAhVsyaYKHQ-MB6IQMwhNKA4wDg..i&w=600&h=460&bih=625&biw=1366&q=Carl%20von.%20Bergen%20painting&ved=0ahUKEwilz76p8aziAhVsyaYKHQ-MB6IQMwhNKA4wDg&iact=mrc&uact=8)).

The painting is titled "Jugend vom Lande" ("Youth in the country"), marked "Made in Germany" and "number 1158" though I don't know if this is Carl von Bergen's painting number or postcard number. I am unable to recognize publisher marking (lower left side of revers of the card).

Most of Carl von Bergen's works were painted by the end of nineteenth century or in the beginning of twentieth century, but this says nothing about the year of publication of this postcard or about the date, it was sent.

Can anyone help in this case?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to G&FH.SE! The logo looks to me like an artist's palette with a brush/stylus through it, and perhaps "Zugi" or "Zigi". I looked on ["The Postcard Album"](http://www.tpa-project.info/), which contains a lot of information about German postcards, but couldn't see that logo. It might be worth contacting them, though.

Comment: According to [Ansichtskartenversand](https://www.ansichtskartenversand.com/ak/136-PC-Lexicon/260-Degi-AK), the logo is that of "Deutsche Gemälde-Industrie Georgi & Co." or short "Degi". Unfortunately this particular card does not seem to be listed.

Comment: Forgot to mention: according to that same page, the publisher itself was active from 1915 to the end of WWII.

Comment: Thank you! The mentioned time period of 30 years (1915-1945) is long, but the information that thus card must be pre-WW2 or from the WW2 period at most, is actually very essential for me. Since it directly answers my question (given in bold), I'd suggest converting your comments into a full featured answer.

Comment: The English "Made in Germany" text would indicate an article made to be exported - then sold at retail. It may be possible that the text in the postage position would be helpful for dating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The publisher logo in the bottom left corner of the reverse side shows this card to have been published by *Deutsche Gemälde-Industrie Georgi & Co.* or *Degi* for short. According to [Ansichtskartenversand](https://www.ansichtskartenversand.com/ak/136-PC-Lexicon/260-Degi-AK) this publisher was active from about 1915 to the end of World War II, with peak popularity of their postcards during the 1920s. I was unable to find a narrower time frame when this postcard series was published. There also do not seem to be any markings dating this particular postcard.